# Why doesn't it remove the table?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I have this piece of code

```
// TR Fading when deleted
$('.delete').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'history/delete/id/'+$(this).attr('id')
    });
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        if($(this).closest('table').find('tbody').is(':empty'))
            $('#latest').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

It triggers when I want to delete a table row through the delete button (as shows the image)
[image http://aviary.com/viewfull?fguid=433f68f6-d18d-102d-a9f3-0030488e168c&nowatermark=true](http://aviary.com/viewfull?fguid=433f68f6-d18d-102d-a9f3-0030488e168c&nowatermark=true)

It may happen that the table becomes empty of table rows. I want to delete the whole table when this occurs, but the table isn't being removed. The line code `$(this).remove();` works and `this` seems to refer to the `tr` element in that scope 'cause the whole row is being removed but the next 2 lines doesn't work. The table isn't being removed.

### EDIT

I changed the `if($(this).closest('table').find('tbody').is(':empty'))` to `if(!$(this).closest('table').find('tbody').is(':empty'))` (exclamation mark) to see if it removes and it removed the whole table, but I inspected the table element before and after deleting the last row and got this

[image http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4344000/4344383_4fbd.png](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4344000/4344383_4fbd.png)

JS says that tbody is not empty, google chrome says otherwise. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Have you check the value of $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').is(':empty') ? May be it is null and if condition is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once you remove it, relative selectors like [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) won't do anything, since that element doesn't have a parent anymore.  Also [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) isn't working because it **includes text nodes**, [from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/content-filter-selector/):

> Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

So `:empty` won't match if there's any white-space left (alert or log `$("latest tbody").html())` to see what I mean), which is almost certainly the case, the same goes for my example below.  Instead you can use [`:has(tr)`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to check for table rows, and [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to negate that, like this:

```
$('.delete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#latest tbody:not(:has(tr))").parent().remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

[You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmJqS/), if the `:not(:has(tr))` selector doesn't match anything...and it won't if there's not a row-less `<tbody>`, it just won't remove anything.

Comment: `which is likely the case.` why is that likely the case? It looks like `remove()` itself creates a whitespace ?

Comment: @jAndy - There was whitespace before the `.remove()`...unless your `<tr>` elements budded right up to each other (no new-line characters) this will be the case, most pages render a row per line though, leaving at least a `\n` in there...remove doesn't remove this text node, just the `<tr></tr>` you told it to :)

Comment: I told it just because out of testing, I had/have not explanation why that is the case.

Comment: Ok, I got it. It's really caused because of the markup. Concatenating all together works with `:empty`.. doh what a mess!

Comment: @jAndy - Yup, for anyone interested, here's a comparison of `.children().length` (number of `<tr>`) to `.contents().length` (all children, what `:empty` checks): http://jsfiddle.net/ZmJqS/2/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `remove()` and `detach()` do leave some kind of **crud** behind after they remove a tr element. It's like a whitespace or a linebreak, so since the `:empty` selector also checks for textnodes, it's not empty at all.

so

```
if($('#latest tbody').children().length() < 1)
   $('#latest').remove();
```

should do the trick.

Reference: http://jsbin.com/esaye3/2/edit

**update**

Like **Nick Craver** mentioned, this behavior is caused by the `HTML markup` itself.

`<tbody><tr><td>Something</td><td>Anything?</td><td><button class="delete">delete</button></td></tr></tbody>`

for instance, WILL work with `:empty` aswell.